# How remove all programs comes from a package?

Tags: apt, uninstall

When you install a program like postgresql, it installs several programs for its last version.

Once installed how remove all those packages? because using

```
apt-get remove postgresql
```

removes only that head package

Comment: Why do you think postgresql is a metapackage which actually it's not!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `apt-get autoremove` (suggested by Aaron) will remove all "helper-packages" nothing seems to depend on any longer, sometimes you want to keep some of them for one reason or another. So if that concerns you, another possibility would be:

```
$(apt-cache depends postgresql|awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove "$NF}')
```

Using Bash as your shell, this would basically do the following:

1. `apt-cache depends postgresql` would list all packages the postgresql depends on, including postgresql itself. But each line would look like `depends on: <package>` -- so we pipe the output to...
2. `awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove "$NF}'` which would take the last word on each line (which is the package name), and prints it out after preceding it with our intended command: `sudo apt-get remove` (you could of course also use `apt-get purge` instead).
3. finally, using the `$()` construct, we advise Bash to interpret the output as command to be executed.

You could alternatively replace the 3rd step and instead redirect the output into a file:

```
apt-cache depends postgresql|awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove "$NF}' >pg_remove.sh
```

And then inspect the file, optionally do some adjustments (such as commenting out/removing lines where you want to keep a package), and finally execute the script using

```
bash pg_remove.sh
```

Now you have a lot of possibilities to chose from :)

**EDIT:** Checking with more complex metapackages as e.g. lubuntu-desktop, above statements needs to be refined:

```
apt-cache depends <packageName>|grep "Depends on"|awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove "$NF}'
```

The `grep` is needed to restrict the result to dependencies (and skip the recommends etc.).

**IMPORTANT: You should use this only for metapackages!!!** otherwise, you may end up with an empty disk (e.g. postgresql-9.1 depends on libc6, and removing libc6 will certainly backfire as it is needed by a lot of packages).

So be careful, and better redirect to a file first (as explained) and investigate before execution.

Comment: `apt-cache depends postgresql` only shows that it depends on _postgresql-9.1_

Comment: That's correct -- but I wouldn't iterate with the remove; postgresql-9.1 itself depends e.g. on libc6, and if you remove that you probably get an empty disk (almost). This said, I must add you should only use this on meta-packages, for the given reasons. In your example, the meta-package seems to hold only this one package -- looking on others I see it gets much more complex, and my above answer would need to be refined (check e.g. with the `lxde` metapackage, or `lubuntu-desktop`...

Comment: Amazing! This is so cool! This may be a silly question, but what do you do about purging the configuration files of the dependencies? If you used the command where you generate a shell script first that can be edited, do you see any problem with changing `apt-get remove` to `apt-get purge` or even` apt-get purge --auto-remove`?

Comment: @Emily if you want that, just add the `--purge` parameter to the command, i.e. `… awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove --purge "$NF}'`.

Answer (score 1):

HIt <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes packages that are no longer needed, which is due to removing a package (such as postgresql) that depends on them.

You can always purge the configuration files with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

To clean even further, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
deborphan
```

Comment: The bad side is that it can not purge packages (remove configuration files) of that metapackage.

Answer (score 0):

Simple follow the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge postgresql
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge `deborphan`
```